# UISplitViewController shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation

Tags: ios, uisplitviewcontroller

I'm using a UISplitViewController and when I launch the simulator, I get the following error:

"The view controller  returned NO from -shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: for all interface orientations. It should support at least one orientation."

Any ideas on why I am getting this? (I am not subclassing the splitview controller).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All of your view controllers INSIDE the split view controller have to override the method. Seems like at least one of your overrides returns NO in all cases. To make it rotate to all orientations, return YES in all overrides.